# Using JpaRepository interface. How can I get the entitymanager to set property?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

All DAO's in my system is only interfaces, like this:

```
public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
    Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

And that's all.

But now I need to set a property at entitymanager.
How can I get the entitymanager in my interface?

The bean is:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
```

But I need to set this property at my DAO because this property depends of the logged user.

Comment: Can you please provide your configuration xml with spring jpa? Usually EntityManager should be configured as a spring bean.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create a custom repository as detailed in the spring-data documentation. This can be done for a single repository or for all repositories.

The process is clearly outlined below.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour